# Email deliverability is off but still receiving Apex Exception emails - is this expected?

Tags: email, exception, deliverability

The Email Deliverability setting is off. As per the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_email_deliverability.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5), all outbound emails to and from users are stopped.

What I'm perplexed about is that I am still receiving some Apex Unhandled Exception emails.

Are exception emails expected to be sent even though the Email Deliverability setting is set to 'off'?
If so, are there any other examples of emails that can still be sent from Salesforce even though Email Deliverability is set to 'off'?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you try disabling 'Send an email each time automation updates the same record' under Setup --> Quick Find --> Process Automation Settings